# Complex query on big table

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a big user table (3M), of structure:

```
age  (int) 
country (FK) 
city (text) 
gender (text) 
active (bool)
```

My objective is to run a search finding 15 users of given age area, gender, city and country (favouring active users).

I'm having two issues, due to the size of the table:

- Even with indexing, it takes a long time (a couple hundred
  miliseconds)
- Results must differ each time the query is ran. Currently I execute
  query with LIMIT 30 and just get random 15 results from it, but the
  30 results are always the same. Whole table is too big to do
  shuffling.

Is there some commonly used solution for overcoming similar issues?

The database server is MySQL, implementation in Django. I also have access to Redis cache.

Comment: A combined index should return results in few ms. I would also avoid using `text` data type because it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

You would save yourself a fortune in time by changing data types to

```
`gender` varchar(1) -- or even `enum('m','f')
`city` varchar (60) -- or something sane like that
```

The index on these would be much more friendly to you and so much smaller. Trust me, the smaller and more exact you can make the data the easier it is to search. I would expect your search time to improve as you wish just by using the lighter (non object, as Manny pints out) data types.

You could try something like `ORDER BY active DESC, RAND()` to select different results each time favouring active users.

If you have a lot of inactive users to filter against then you might want to create a temporary table for just active users but to be honest these sorts of optimisations are case specific and a few tests are sometimes the best way to know if they are worth your while.